# How can one use the post position -(이)라든지?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Most uses of -(이)라든지 that I have seen are used in the context of "either this or that"

> 치킨이라든지 피자라든지 미국 음식을 먹고 싶다.
>
> (I want to eat American food, whether it be chicken or pizza).

However, it seems that I've also seen it used to mean "and the like" before. Here is an example of how I think -(이)라든지 *could* be used in this way:

> 치킨이라든지 미국 음식을 먹고 싶다.
>
> (I want to eat American food, chicken and whatnot)

Can -(이)라든지 be used in this way?

Answer (score 2):

> A이라든지, B이라든지 C : C is representative word for A, B
>
> A이라든지 B : B is representative word for A

Chulsoo is more outstanding in exercise than Younghee, for instance,
soccer.

철수는 축구라든지, 운동 면에서 영희를 앞 지른다.

> A이라든지 B : B and A share equal position.

I could not read a frustration or a disappointment in his eye.

나는 그의 눈에서 좌절이라든지 낙심의 빛을 찾지 못했다 (We can not read any bad thing, for instance frustration or disappointment).